# UIBarButtonItem Selector Function Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

All I did create a simple UIBarButtonItem but my action function won't be called for some reason no idea why (i.e. my breakpoint won't even get hit).
Here is a screenshot of the code.
[image]

Comment: replace HomePageViewController with self.

Comment: How you are using addReminder block ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is not being called [because](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232):

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other property values from within your closure, even if those properties have default values.

moreover:

> You also cannot use the implicit self property, or call any of the instance’s methods.

to solve this issue (cannot access to `self` during the initialization) you might declare such `UIBarButtonItem` as `lazy var`, so it will be created safely after the `ViewController` has been initialized:

```
lazy var addReminder:UIBarButtonItem = {
    return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(HomePageViewController.addNewReminder))
}()
```